# Generating digits $0$ to $9$ with a coin

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-probability

You're given a fair coin. The goal is to use it to generate a random decimal digit.

I didn't find any solutions on the internet, so I came up with one myself. It goes as follows:

> Assign $0$ to heads and $1$ to tails. To the first ten binary numbers (starting with zero), assign the decimal digits from $0$ to $9$. Do the same to the binary versions of 10 through 19 and 20 through 29. The binary numbers corresponding to 30 and 31 must be discarded, and the procedure outlined below must be carried out again.
>
> Toss the coin five times, this will generate a 5-tuple of ones and zeros. This 5-tuple can be viewed as a binary number (with the obvious condition to ignore the leading zero or zeros). By the assignment scheme outlined above, every 5-tuple corresponds to a decimal digit (except the binary 30 and 31 that should be ignored).

*Note:* I chose 5-tuples over 4-tuples because with 4-tuples, the whole procedure is less effective (a much larger portion of the possible outcomes must be discarded).

My question: **Is there a simpler way to generate a random decimal digit using a fair coin than the one I've described?**

Comment: There are as many ways to generate decimal digits using a coin as you wish to spend the time thinking up.  For example heads is 3, tails is 7.  This will give you 3 and 7 with equal probability, and all other digits with zero probability.  Even if you insist that all digits be equally probable, there are other schemes which you could implement.  What you propose is close to the most straight-forward solution, however.

Comment: @RossMillikan true. Fixed.

Comment: As a variant, use your system to generate a "decimal" in base $2$.  Stop when it is clear that your value lies between $\frac i{10}$ and $\frac {i+1}{10}$ at which point you have chosen the digit $i$.  In theory this may never halt, but that problem is unavoidable.

Comment: @lulu If I'm not mistaken, this method minimizes the expected number of flips you have to do. I came across it in a coding competition, which mentioned it as the best in the above regard, but I don't have a proof of it.

Comment: @lulu It's a smidgen more convoluted, but I think it's the best approach if you want as few throws as possible, and to halt as quickly as possible. From the third or fourth toss, if it hasn't halted yet, each toss has a $0.5$ probability of halting the process.

Comment: @Arthur  Yes, that's the advantage.  In practice, it halts very quickly.

Comment: @Stefan4024  In principle I believe the claim, but I don't know how to even attack it.  The space of possible strategies is pretty amorphous.

Comment: Note that you can shave some inefficiency off the rerolling in the original scheme if you use the first instance of $30$ vs $31$ to split into two cases of five each ($0$-$29$ decides directly, $30$ means we're deciding between $0$-$4$ and $31$ means we're deciding between $5$-$9$, for instance), meaning you don't start entirely from scratch (and can indeed get away penalty free with only four tosses per round after that point, rerolling if we get a total of $15$).

Comment: @Arthur that's a very cool idea..

Comment: To the downvoter: what is the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice simple approach.  If you just reroll entirely when you get $30$ or $31$ you use on average $\frac {32}{30}\cdot 5=\frac {16}3$ flips per digit.

You can do better at the cost of some complexity.  You need at least an average of $\log_2 (10)\approx 3.322$ flips per digit.  If you flip $10$ times you generate a number from $0$ to $1023$.  If it is less than $1000$ you have three digits.  If it is $1000-1019$ you have one digit.  Ten flips then give you on average $\frac {1000\cdot 3 + 20\cdot 1}{1024}\approx 2.949$ bits or we use about $3.391$ flips per digit, which is not far from the optimum.

To do better yet, throw $332193$ flips and generate a huge binary number.  Most of the time you will get $100\ 000$ decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

With $4$ tosses, you toss on average $\dfrac{16}{10}4=\dfrac{32}5$ times per digit.

With $5$ tosses, you toss on average $\dfrac{32}{30}5=\dfrac{16}3$ times per digit.

So $5$ is the optimum.

Comment: Well, I mentioned that in my question...

Comment: @vomadaxela: you didn't give the figures.

Comment: You are right, I was talking about the fact that 5 is the optimal choice. It's nice to see the figures, but I don't see how this answers my question. This should be a comment, IMO.

Comment: @vomadaxela: by giving the figures, it becomes obvious that $6$ and more cannot be better.

Comment: You are right, but I was asking for an approach that is completely different from the one I gave.

Comment: @vomadaxela: completely different is a little hard. If the drawings of the digits are independent, all you can do is toss $k$ times, and $k=5$ is optimal, full  stop. If you allow simultaneous drawings of digits (e.g. $10$ bits giving $3$ digits, $3.41$ times per digit), the optimal is $k=\infty$ ($3.3219$ per digit).

Comment: @vomadaxela: but these procedures are by no means simpler.